# "J'ai oublié" vs "J'oublie"?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

In English, the correct statement is "I forgot," but people commonly say "I forget," which frankly infuriates me.

So far in French I've been carrying that principle over and saying "J'ai oublié," but I realized that for all I know, that is not correct in French. So which is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is indeed not correct to say “*J’oublie*” when talking about something you ***forgot*** to do.

However, it can be used aptly to express the fact that you always forget to do/say/whatever something, which would be said “*J’oublie à chaque fois !*”.

It does not matter that you talk about the past since you insist upon the idea you never do it.